# How to generate .PDB files for Asp.net Website while building code or load symbols for Asp.net website with snapshot debugger

Tags: azure, debugging, azure-application-insights, snapshot, pdb-files

I am able to generate pdb(PDB is an abbreviation for Program Data Base. As the name suggests, it is a repository (persistent storage such as databases) to maintain information required to run your program in debug mode. It contains many important relevant information required while you debug your code (in Visual Studio), for e.g. at what points you have inserted break points where you expect the debugger to break in Visual Studio.) files from Asp.NET Web Application,but fail while building Asp.NET Website,
I need these pdb files for Symbols to load from Snapshot debugger(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/snapshot-debugger) of Application Insights in Azure environment.
Is it possible to generate pdb files from Asp.NET Website? or 
Is there any other way to load symbols for Asp.NET Website snapshot debugger of Application Insights?